# Loopback, How could I get datasource name of a model?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

`Model.getDatasource().name` returns the connector name while I want to get the data source name, any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Datasource Id :**

if your model is a PersistedModel, then use :

```
    Model.getSourceId(function(err, sourceId) {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Datasource', sourceId); // SourceId is a string
    })
```

check [this](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-getsourceid) official documentation.

**Connector Name**

```
var connector = Model.getDataSource().connector;
    console.log(connector.name);
```

**Datasource Name**

```
var dataSourceName = Model.getDataSource().settings.name;

Model.getDataSource().settings
```

==> prints all your datasource settings

Comment: This returns data source id, something like "mongodb-User", i.e <connector>-<modelName> while I want the the datasource name.

Comment: @AhmedIsmail yes you are right sorry for missunderstanding can you check mu edited answer is this name that you want ?

Comment: Model.getDataSource().connector.name also returns the connector name not the DS name :)

Comment: @AhmedIsmail Ah ok, understood i'll get to you later :)

Comment: @AhmedIsmail check my last edit -- > datasource Name :)

Comment: yes Model.getDataSource().settings.name did it, thanks.